# Magento 2.1 - Title Prefix/Suffix doesn't show

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, seo

I've set my webshop Titles prefix/suffixes in **Content > Design: Configuration > HTML Head** for every level (from global to website to store) and I haven't overwritten the head.phtml in my theme. Still the `<title>` tags only show the page- or categorynames. I've seen this behaviour on several Magento2 sites. Is this a bug?

Comment: Which version Have you used? magento 2.1.1 or 2.1.2?

Comment: Both. It never worked from 2.0 up to 2.1.2

Comment: In my system its working fine. For magento 2.1.1

Comment: Have you set inside your theme?

Comment: As said in the question; no, I haven't edited anything from the base theme regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't working because the inserted value was starting with a blank space. Try to trim the suffix. Ex "- my website" instead of " - my website" Hope it helps